# Loop through then reset an array in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, foreach, numbers

Edit: ive attempted something similar to this:

```
let firstarray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
let secondarray = ["1", "2", "3"]
let currentindex = 0;
if(currentindex == secondarray.length) {
currentindex - secondarry.length
}
firstarray.forEach(item => {
console.log(`${item} ${secondarray[currentindex]}`)
currentindex++
});
```

would this work or is there anything similar I can do?

Simple explanation:

```
//I have 2 arrays:
let firstarray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
let secondarray = ["1", "2", "3"]
//how can i log both of these but repeat through the second array as such:
"one 1"
"two 2"
"three 3"
"four 1"
"five 2"
"six 3"
```

Not so simple explanation:

im looking to attempt to basically loop through an array repeatedly, and example would be:

```
let myarray = ["1", "2", "3"] //multiple strings
```

Above is my array, I know that if I do this:

```
console.log(myarray[0])
```

it returns 1 and if i do this:

```
myarray.forEach(item => {
console.log(item)
});
```

it logs 1 then 2 then 3 but this depends on the array itself.

Lets say I have another array with 6 items:

```
let firstarray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
let secondarray = ["1", "2", "3"]
 firstarray.forEach(item => {
console.log(`${item}`)
});
```

This logs:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

How could I make it log and loop the second array also, so it returns this:

```
"one 1"
"two 2"
"three 3"
"four 1"
"five 2"
"six 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulus of the second array length...

```
firstarray.forEach((num, index) => {
    console.log(num + " " + secondarray[index % secondarray.length])
})
```

outputs:

```
"one 1"
"two 2"
"three 3"
"four 1"
"five 2"
"six 3"
```

Comment: So im guessing to store the second value as a variable then:
`let secondvalue = secondarray[index % secondarray.length]` would work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it for any 2 arrays (not knowing which one is bigger)

```
//get the biggest array's length
var maxLen = Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length);
for(var i = 0;i<maxLen;i++) {
    //get the elements mod the length to wrap around
    var ele1 = arr1[i % arr1.length];
    var ele2 = arr2[i % arr2.length];
    console.log(ele1 + " " + ele2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through both arrays with a single index, taking the remainder of that index for the second array.

```js
let firstarray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
let secondarray = ["1", "2", "3"]
let index = -1
while (++index < firstarray.length) {
  console.log(firstarray[index], secondarray[index % secondarray.length])
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this strictly inside of the foreach:
`let firstarray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
let secondarray = ["1", "2", "3"]
firstarray.forEach(item => {
//everything done here
});`

Answer (score 0):

Ive figured it out!

```
let firstarray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
let secondarray = ["1", "2", "3"]
let currentindex = 0;
firstarray.forEach(item => {
console.log(`${item} ${secondarray[currentindex]}`)
currentindex++
if(currentindex === secondarray.length) {
  currentindex -= secondarray.length
}
});
```

Returns what i wanted!